# How to add objects to an objects array while using a property to determine the order of the objects inside this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, data-structures

I have an array of objects where each one represents a rule. They all have an attribute "priority" (integer), which determines their importance (the one with the highest priority is the most important). The user can edit an aexisting rule (object), but here's the catch:

- If the user sets the priority to one that already exists, say 1, this modified rule will have to take the place of the other rule with the same priority;
- This other rule will then have to change its priority to the number immediately after the modified rule's priority. Any pre-existing rule will likely have to change their priority, unless there is space between 2 neighboring priorities (rule[1] has a priority of 2, while rule[2] has a priority of 4, for instance).

I'm using `BootstrapTable` from `react-bootstrap-table-next` to display the rules (1 rule per row). The first column is the Priority. The user can edit it by clicking on it.

```
<BootstrapTable
   cellEdit={cellEdit}
   keyField={"id"}
   responsive
   bordered={false}
   striped={false}
   defaultSorted={defaultSorted}
   classes={"table align-middle table-wrap"}
   headerWrapperClasses={"thead-light"}
   columns={colunas}
   data={stateLinhas}
   filter={filterFactory()}
 />
```

The `data` attribute is the state (`stateLinhas`) the contains the array of objects. The built-in functions I'm using are the following:

```
afterSaveCell: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
  stateLinhas.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.prioridade < b.prioridade) {
      return -1
    } else if (a.prioridade > b.prioridade) {
      return 1
    }
    return 0
  })
},
beforeSaveCell: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => {
  let aux = stateLinhas
  aux.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (parseInt(newValue) === parseInt(item.prioridade)) {
      item.prioridade = parseInt(newValue) + 1
    }
  })
  setStateLinhas(() => aux)
}
```

With this code it changes the priority of the first array it encounters with the same priority.

Can anybody help me to do this with JavaScript? I've been wrecking my brain for days and got nowhere.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Please add minimal reproducible code

Comment: Can there be ever at least two rules that share the same priority at the same time?

Comment: Is the order in which the objects appear in the array of any importance? If not, then why not use the index an object has in the array as its priority? If yes, can you clarify what that is about? Secondly, can you provide sample input and demonstrate which actions have which effect on that array?

Comment: Please also explain the bigger picture. It is not efficient to potentially have to update *all* objects when inserting a new object. There are likely better ways to accomplish what you need at a higher level. Also, is it fair that if I have a priority 1 object in the array, and add an object with priority 1 and then one with priority 2, that the original object gets priority 3? If the two insertions happen in the reversed order, it will end up with priority 2... This seems a strange system to manage priorities.

Comment: Hey guys. Thank you for taking the time. I edited the question with some code. Also I mistakenly thought I need to let the users add a rule, but for now I only need to allow them to edit their priorities.

Comment: Do the elements have to keep their priority values after a change or just appropriately change to keep the relative ordering?  That is, if I have `[a1, b2, c4, d5, e8, f9, g10]` and I have to change `f` to priority `4`, does the answer have to be `[a1, b2, f4, c5, d6, e8, g10]`?  Or could it just be `[a1, b2, f4, c5, d6, e7, g8]`?  Or even better, just `[a1, b2, f3, c4, d5, e6, g7]`?

Comment: @PeterO, limiting to updates doesn't resolve the mentioned issues. I had hoped your edit would have included the bigger picture, the higher level need,...

Comment: The elements have to change to keep the relative ordering only if the edited priority already exists in another object. If you have [a1, b2, c4, d5, e8, f9, g10] and change f to priority to 4, the answer would be [a1, b2, f4, c5, d6, e8, f9, g10]. No priority needs to change if it is unique in the array.

Comment: @trincot let me be more specific: You only have to update the objects if after the edit there are 2 or more objects with the same priority. You are right to think that if I have a priority 1 object in the array, and modify an object with priority 1 and then one with priority 2, that the original object gets priority 3. That's exactly how it is supposed to work. If the modifications happen in the reversed order, the original object with priority 1 will  end up with priority 2, because the last edited add 1 to an object, and it took the place of the original object with priority 1.

Comment: Yes, I get how you imagine it to work. But there must be better ideas for your needs. What is the priority about? Tell us the bigger picture. Why is it needed that gaps in the priority sequence are maintained and not shifted into? What is the purpose of the entries in this list? What is expected from this priority?

Comment: "No priority needs to change if it is unique in the array."  But *may* it change if it doesn't affect the relative ordering?  I can think of a very simple solution that will put the newly changed item in the right place, and keep the relative ordering intact, but will not keep the actual ordering values.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: Repeating an earlier comment to which I would still like to know the answers: *Is the order in which the objects appear in the array of any importance? If not, then why not use the index an object has in the array as its priority? If yes, can you clarify what that is about? Secondly, can you provide sample input and demonstrate which actions have which effect on that array?*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood your problem correctly. But from what i read you can do something like below.

Here each time while adding we get the index of matching priority. If not found we simply push the new Rule. However if index is found we splice and insert the new rule. After inserting we then keep checking next priority and if it is same as previous we simple increment it.

```js
const rules = [];

function addRule() {
    const priority = document.getElementById('priority').value;
    const newRule = {priority: parseInt(priority)};
  
    const index = rules.findIndex(rule => rule.priority === newRule.priority);
  if (index !== -1) {
    rules.splice(index, 0, newRule);
    let currentPriority = newRule.priority;
    rules.map((rule, i) => {
        if (i > index) {
        if (rule.priority === currentPriority) {
            rule.priority++;
          currentPriority = rule.priority;
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    rules.push(newRule);
  }
  
  console.log(rules);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="priority" placeholder="enter priority">
<button onclick="addRule()">
Add Rule
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I edited the question. I thought the user could add a new rule, but for now he just needs to edit their priority. Sorry, that was on me.

Answer (score 1):

The base of any approach could be a utility function which accepts an array of rule items and does mutate such an array by ...

- first rearranging all array items by ascending `priority` values.
- second (continuously) recalculating the 2nd `priority` value within a sequence (pair) of 2 consecutive same `priority` values.

The 2nd part gets achieved by looking for an initial occurrence of such 2 consecutive same `priority` values. The continues recalculation task starts at the index of this initial occurrence and stops as soon as no following pair of consecutive same `priority` values appears.

The validity of both the initial and the later added rule-data can be ensured by e.g. the implementation of an own `Rule` type. Thus the utility function's implemented algorithm always operates a valid `rules` array.

```js
// module scope ... local scope.

function rePrioritizeRules(rules) {
  // function is going to mutate any passed array.

  // - rearrange array items by ascending priority values.
  rules.sort((a, b) =>
    a.priority - b.priority
  );
  let currentRule, currentPriority, previousPriority, nextPriority;

  // - find index at which the first precedence of
  //   two consecutive same priority values occurs.
  let idx = rules.findIndex((rule, idx) =>
    rule.priority === rules[idx + 1]?.priority
  );
  let proceed = (idx >= 0); // - there is an initial case of two
                            //   consecutive same priority values.
  while (proceed) {
    currentRule = rules[++idx];

    currentPriority = currentRule.priority;
    previousPriority = rules[idx - 1]?.priority;
    nextPriority = rules[idx + 1]?.priority;

    if (previousPriority === currentPriority) {
      currentRule.priority = currentPriority + 1;
    }
    proceed = (nextPriority === currentRule.priority);
  }
  return rules;
}

/*export */class Rules {
  #rules = [];

  constructor(initialRules = []) {
    const rules = Array
      .from(initialRules)
      .sort((a, b) => (a.priority ?? 0) - (b.priority ?? 0));

    // guard ... ensures an initially valid array of rule items.
    if (
      rules.every(({ priority }, idx) =>
        Number.isSafeInteger(priority) &&
        (rules[idx - 1]?.priority ?? Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) < priority
      )
    ) {
      this.#rules = rules;
    }
  }

  valueOf() {
    return structuredClone(this.#rules);
  }

  addRule(rule = {}) {
    const { priority } = rule;

    // guard.
    if (!Number.isSafeInteger(priority)) {
      return;
    }
    this.#rules.push(rule);

    rePrioritizeRules(this.#rules);
  }
}

const initialRulesSetting = [{
  rule: "baz",
  priority: 5,
}, {
  rule: "foo",
  priority: 2,
}, {
  rule: "bar",
  priority: 4,
}, {
  rule: "biz",
  priority: 6,
}];
const rules = new Rules(initialRulesSetting);
console.log(rules.valueOf());

rules.addRule({ rule: "fooFoo", priority: 1 });
console.log(rules.valueOf());

rules.addRule({ rule: "fooFooFoo", priority: 1 });
console.log(rules.valueOf());

rules.addRule({ rule: "fooBar", priority: 3 });
console.log(rules.valueOf());

rules.addRule({ rule: "fooBarBar", priority: 4 });
console.log(rules.valueOf());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I edited the question. I thought the user could add a new rule, but for now he just needs to edit their priority. Sorry, that was on me.

Answer (score 0):

The following class allows to insert, remove, access head and tail items, search previous and next items by priority, and dump all contents of the queue. It uses sparse Array to map priorities directly to items, and doubly linked list to quickly jump from one item to another.

Two major downsides in this implementation though. First, is that `insert`, `prev`, and `next` methods are using incremental seeking whenever specified priority doesn't exist: all undefined priorities have to be skipped until the next defined one is found. Second, *all* items with consecutive priorities are updated in `insert`.

Apart from that, already existing priority items should be accessed in O(1) to O(log n) time (*JS engines may use linear in-memory layout for arrays that are populated incrementally; and only convert them into heaps when they become too sparse, or their index has been altered by (un)shifting/splicing*).

This is definitely not the optimal way to get the job done. But if your queues are not gonna have large gaps between items or long consecutive sequences, and you don't plan to use them in a bottleneck, then it should be fine.

```js
class ShiftingPriorityQueue {

    #array;
    #head;
    #tail;
    #size;

    constructor () { this.clear(); }

    insert (value, priority) {

        this.#size++;
        let array = this.#array;
        let item = { value, priority, prev: null, next: null };

        // the queue is empty
        if (this.#head == null) {
            this.#head = item;
            this.#tail = item;
            array[priority] = item;
            return;
        }

        // this priority is the highest in the queue
        if (priority >= array.length) {
            item.prev = this.#tail;
            this.#tail.next = item;
            this.#tail = item;
            array[priority] = item;
            return;
        }

        let rearrangeArray;

        // this priority is undefined, search the next defined one
        if (!array[priority]) {
            rearrangeArray = false;
            array[priority] = item;
            while (!array[++priority]);
        }

        // this priority is already defined
        else {
            rearrangeArray = true;
        }

        // insert new item into the doubly linked list
        let nextItem = array[priority];
        let prevItem = nextItem.prev;
        if (prevItem) {
            item.prev = prevItem;
            prevItem.next = item;
        }
        else {
            this.#head = item;
        }
        item.next = nextItem;
        nextItem.prev = item;

        if (rearrangeArray) {
            // increment priorities of consecutive items,
            // and push them forward until the gap is reached
            while (array[priority]) {
                array[priority++] = item;
                item = item.next;
                item.priority++;
            }
            array[priority] = item;
        }
    }

    delete (priority) {

        let array = this.#array;

        // this priority is undefined
        if (!array[priority]) {
            return;
        }

        // delete item from the doubly linked list
        let item = array[priority];
        let prevItem = item.prev;
        let nextItem = item.next;
        if (prevItem) {
            prevItem.next = nextItem;
        }
        else {
            this.#head = nextItem;
        }
        if (nextItem) {
            nextItem.prev = prevItem;
        }
        else {
            this.#tail = prevItem;
        }

        // delete item from the array
        delete array[priority];

        // if it was the tail item, then shrink the array
        if (this.#tail == prevItem) {
            array.length = prevItem? prevItem.priority + 1: 0;
        }

        this.#size--;
    }

    has (priority) { return !!this.#array[priority]; }
    get (priority) { return this.#array[priority]?.value; }

    prev (priority) {

        if (!this.#head || priority <= this.#head.priority) {
            return;
        }
        if (priority > this.#tail.priority) {
            return this.#tail.priority;
        }
        let array = this.#array;
        if (array[priority]) {
            return array[priority].prev.priority;
        }
        while (!array[--priority]);
        return priority;
    }

    next (priority) {

        if (!this.#tail || priority >= this.#tail.priority) {
            return;
        }
        if (priority < this.#head.priority) {
            return this.#head.priority;
        }
        let array = this.#array;
        if (array[priority]) {
            return array[priority].next.priority;
        }
        while (!array[++priority]);
        return priority;
    }

    get head () { return this.#head?.priority; }
    get tail () { return this.#tail?.priority; }
    get size () { return this.#size; }

    all () {

        let item = this.#head;
        let result = [];
        while (item) {
            result.push({ value: item.value, priority: item.priority });
            item = item.next;
        }
        return result;
    }

    clear () {

        this.#array = [];
        this.#head = null;
        this.#tail = null;
        this.#size = 0;
    }
}

let queue = new ShiftingPriorityQueue();

function testInsert (value, priority) {
    queue.insert(value, priority);
    console.log(`insert(${value}, ${priority})`);
    console.log(queue.all());
}

function testDelete (priority) {
    queue.delete(priority);
    console.log(`remove(${priority})`);
    console.log(queue.all());
}

function testQueries (priority) {
    console.log(
        `has(${priority}) = ${(queue.has(priority)+';').padEnd(11)}` +
        `prev(${priority}) = ${queue.prev(priority)}\n` +
        `get(${priority}) = ${(queue.get(priority)+';').padEnd(11)}` +
        `next(${priority}) = ${queue.next(priority)}`
    );
}

testInsert('Alice', 3);
testInsert('Bob', 5);
testInsert('John', 7);
testInsert('Jane', 1);
testInsert('Kate', 5);
testInsert('Dick', 5);

testDelete(5);
testDelete(queue.head);
testDelete(queue.tail);

for (let i = 0; i < queue.tail + 3; i++) {
    testQueries(i);
}
```

*Leave a comment if something doesn't work.*